# Installing Magento 2 on localhost using WAMP gives me Page Not Found for Backend, no styling for Frontend

Tags: magento, wamp, wampserver, magento2

I tried to install Magento 2 on localhost using WAMP (php5.5, APACHE2.4.9 and MySQL5.6).

I added the required extension "intl" (by removing (;) in php.ini), but for some reason it didn't work - I had to copy the dll into the Apache bin folder.

I updated xdebug and had to create in php.ini an entry for `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 50000;`.

After all this I went to do the second phase of installation (database creation, etc...) and at the end it was successful. But upon trying to enter the Backend admin page, I get the error Page Not Found, and the Frontend was broken (no style).

So I installed the version with sample-date and the same thing happened, the only difference was the existence of the photos. I installed using the composer, and got the same error.

I think I did something wrong with the WAMP installation, but I'm not sure.

Another issue I encountered was on the themes in the installation with setup wizard: the app / design / frontend / magento folders are empty, while the github repository has two themes - why is that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in other language not english

Comment: SO is an English language site. All other languages are off topic.

Comment: I'm sorry , I'm new in the community, and cheated with the languages . But as I turn the question?

Comment: It because of permission problem better solution is install a new magento2 with full folder permission

Comment: I installed xampp , and used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost , and it worked, but he is very slow and does not save the changes to the backend. I read something about using vagrant environment, try and check it again, but thanks for your answer , really this problem must be on the permissions .

Comment: It is possibly very slow, since you have xdebug enabled. Also, your setting of `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 50000` is too high. Officially windows is not supported, and it is not recommended to run magento2 in production mode on windows.

Comment: oh yes, but using the xampp left Standard ( 256 ) , and you are certain is not supported, so I found many problems using , but I'm already providing another production environment, thanks :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For broken styles and JS, please run [`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html). You might want to provide your specific language code as input; default is `en_US`

Re empty theme folder, there are several methods to [deploy and install](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html), based on your needs. The github version is meant for [contributing devs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html), and hence there are themes present in the `app/design/` folder. However, if you deployed via composer, or downloaded the zip file from magento.com, the `app/design` folder will be empty, since the themes are loaded via composer, from the `vendor/magento` folder.